# android downloading and naming mp3 file

Tags: android, download, filenames, sd-card

I am downloading mp3 file from internet and storing them into my SDCARD i am giving that mp3 file name as a server has given i.e if i am downloading 
test.mp3 file then i am giving name it to test.mp3 and storing into SDCARD

But now my requirement is to giving them name as 1 2 3 like this..
how can i do this
currently i am doing using substring function like this

```
GlobalVariable.Setstrpath(temp1[0].toString().substring(
                        temp1[0].toString().length() - 15,// 15
                        temp1[0].toString().length()))
```

i am saving them into SDCARD/DOWNLOAD folder
how it can be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find another solution also

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ringtones.size(); i++) {

            String s = Ringtones.get(i).toString();
            Log.i("TEST", s.toString());

            String str = s.toString().substring(0, s.indexOf(".mp3"));

            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
            int cntr = Integer.parseInt(str);

            System.out.println("TEST " + cntr);

            System.out.println(cntr + 1);
            GlobalVariable.SetCounter(cntr + 1);

            GlobalVariable.Setstrpath(GlobalVariable.GetCounter() + ".mp3");

        }
```

still better solution is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.i("TEST 1 ", Ringtones.size() + "");


    if (Ringtones.size() == 0) {
        GlobalVariable.SetCounter(1);
    } else {
        GlobalVariable.SetCounter(Ringtones.size() + 1);
    }
    GlobalVariable.Setstrpath(GlobalVariable.GetCounter() + ".mp3");
```

```
Right now i am using this solution
please suggest me if any best solution if available thanks Pragna
```